# How can i count all grouped item from another table?

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with tags. I used this query to fetch them in a loop:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tags ORDER BY name ASC limit 0,25
```

Now, i have a link-table in MySQL to put a tag to more items.
The fields in the 'tags_items' table are as following:

itemID, TagID, tagType.

How can I count the number of tags per piece in one query?

Comment: you mean count tags per item?

Comment: Yes! That is what i mean! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT `itemID`, count(`TagID`) as TagID, GROUP_CONCAT(name) as TagName 
FROM `tags_items` 
inner join `tags` T 
on (T.id = TagID) WHERE 1 
group by `itemID`
```

This query will show the number of tags per item.

Comment: Thanks... how can i combine this with my first query, to display the tags? I think a join is perfect?

Comment: @Jack Vonderberg, I've edited my answer as you needed. I hope it's perfect.